# Sufixo e Prefixo de uma string. Pegar pedaço que sirva de ambos

Tags: c#

Preciso fazer uma função que retorne o Length de uma parte da string que seja tanto sufixo como prefixo. Assim: Dada a string: abbabba, a resposta seria 4, pois seria isso:

Prefixo:

```
a ab abb abba abbab abbabb
```

Sufixo:

```
a ba bba abba babba bbabba
```

Logo abba é tanto prefixo como sufixo. Como eu faço isso?

Comecei assim e não consigo e só me resta mais 10 min.

```
public int teste(string nome)
        {

            string[] pre = new string[nome.Length];
            string[] suf = new string[nome.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < nome.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                pre = nome[i].ToString();// Erro aqui
            }

        }
```

Comment: Tem um objetivo? Ou a ideia é puramente didática?

Comment: Estou fazendo um teste e posso fazer pesquisa sobre o teste então não há nada de fraudulento.

Comment: não sei como ficaria o código c# mas, você pode contar a lenght da string, fazer um for para criar um array para o prefixo e outro para o sufixo com cada uma das variações como demonstrou na pergunta para  depois comparar os dois para pegar os valores que estão presentes nos dois. No fim é só pegar o que possui o lenght maior e você terá seu (su)prefixo.

Comment: Não é o maior length, mas os que forem iguais, aí sim, eu pego esse length.

Comment: só contar os iguais entao, ao inves do maior length como o @RodrigoBorth disse

Comment: Essa é exatamente minha dúvida. Fiz uma edição no post.

Comment: no fim você pode pegar o lenght de todos e verificar qual é o maior e retornar o valor

Comment: "Estou fazendo um teste e posso fazer pesquisa" - isto nao é pesquisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz um `while` que vai comparando o começo com o final até chegar na metade

```
String nome = "abbabba";

var i = 0; // começo
var j = nome.Length-1; // fim, -1 porque começo do 0
var tamanho = 0;
var sufixoEprefixo = "";

while (i <= j) {
    if (nome[i] == nome[j]) { // mesmo caracter
        tamanho++;
        sufixoEprefixo += nome[i];
    } else { // se for diferente pode parar 
        break;
    }
    i++; // avança letra
    j--; // retrocede letra
}
Console.WriteLine(tamanho);
Console.WriteLine(sufixoEprefixo);
```

> 4
>
> abba

### [IdeOne Exemplo](http://ideone.com/CkFTyW)

Comment: Pena que meu tempo já terminou.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como ficaria o código em C#, mas vamos ao passo a passo:

**1** Passe a string para a função
 **2** Declare 1 array para prefixos e 1 array para sufixos
 **3** Declare 1 variavel para contar quantos prefixos são iguais aos
    sufixos
 **4** preencha o array de prefixos
 **5** preencha o array de sufixos
 **6** para cada elemento no array de prefixos, verifique se ele está no
    array de sufixos
 
   **6.1** se estiver, some 1 na sua variavel 
 **7** retorne a variável

**NOTA**: Você não vai igualar o vetor a uma string, você vai adicionar a string ao vetor.

Comment: Nome[i] é um char e não uma string

Comment: é mesmo! mas a outra nota continua válida

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como fica em C#,mas vou dar a resposta em com a logica e você pode aplicar ela no seu caso.

```
var String = "abbabba";
var len = String.length; //Aqui você terá o tamanho da sua string
var array1, array2;
var lenfinal;


para(i=1;i<=len;i++){
    array1[i] = String.caracter(0,i);
    array2[len-i] = String.caracter(len-i,i);
}

//Nesse ponto você deveria ter 2 arrays(array1 e array2) com todos os prefixos e sufixos da string

para(u=0;u<len;u++) {
    if(array1[u] estacontidoem array2){
        lenfinal = array[u].length;
    }
}

imprime(lenfinal);
```

É basicamente isso, só aplicar em C# agora

Nesse caso acredito que a resposta correta seria 7. Pois como temos um palindromo a palavra inteira pode ser sufixo e prefixo ao mesmo tempo

Comment: Tem interesse em aprender C#? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc